# Add to cart not working

Tags: jquery, magento

I am working on a theme for magento and I have two problems. One is when I click an item to see its page and click adding to cart, it doesn't add up. When looked in console I found "productaddtocartform is undefined" also when I go to checkout the step-by-step accordian isn't working. I believe these two things are interlinked? How can I fix it?

Comment: show us some code or solve your self ??

Comment: @Baadshah [link](http://genuinelyjanestudios.ammarworx.com/gjs-books)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your jquery is confilcting with prototype. Use noConflict for that.

I think that would solve

Comment: js error in your script.js

add ',' after animation: "slide"
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: "thumbnails"
 });
 //alert("helo world");
});

Answer (score 0):

Did you install jQuery in your theme? check if you have the no.Conflict file and also try to load first jQuery then jQuery No conflict and finally Prototype.  I had a problem similar to that once due to that. I hope this help!

PS: Also check if you have jQuery loading once or more than once!

Comment: I did do noConflict but now the homepage slider isn't working

Comment: Hard to tell if I don't have the link to your website. I'll check the variable of your slider, try changing them from $ to jQuery